# Terminating the ongoing process and current activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am stumped on this issue, my `onBackPressed()` method doesn't work when it has to. My scenario is as soon as activity starts, progress dialog shows up because I called `asynctask.execute()` in onCreate. When the process takes long time I want to give user a feature that he can dismiss the ongoing process(downloading data from the server) so I tried to dismiss the dialog and finish the activity when back button is pressed, but it's not working.

When I normally press back button after I have got the data, then the control seems to be flowing under `onBackPressed()`.

**Below is my code snippet:**

```
public void onBackPressed() {

            if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
                         finish();


        }
```

Is there any other way to give user an opportunity to cancel that anytime. Please suggest me how to make the entire process and activity terminated when the user presses back button.

Answer (score 0):

For canceling the progress dialogue please set progress dialog cancel as true.

```
dialog.setCancelable(true);
```